# ASP.net : What is the interest of <asp:?

Tags: asp.net

I have a very simple question for which I can't seem to find an explicit answer :
What is the purpose of the `<asp:` tag ?

I mean, if I am building a form for example, what will be the difference between a `<label>` (html tag) and a `<asp:label>` (asp tag I guess) (same question applies for other items) ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a name-prefix. Linking up to a defined .NET library.

Those controls always have the `runat=server` attribute too, and that is the relevant part.

To see how the prefix works, create a simple UserControl and drag it onto a Form. The `<uc1:` tag follows the same principles and is fully defined inside your Form.

Comment: So I guess it's not always usefull to put it ?

I mean for example if I want to create my log in form, I can as well create a "classical" HTML form, it won't really make a difference, will it ?

Comment: The Server controls do add some value. Try out the `<asp:calendar />`.

Comment: Okay I think I see your point.

In the end using ASP tag or classical HTML tag is really a matter of what you need and how you want to render it, right ? 
I mean you don't have to always use ASP tag, it's just some added value you can use whenever you want

Comment: Yes. In general everything you want to program against (serverside) should be an ASP server control. Layout and JavaScript support is done with plain HTML controls.

Answer (score 1):

The former is an HTML tag that will be rendered out verbatim to be interpreted by the web browser. The latter, if it also contains a `runat="server"` attribute, is a directive to ASP.NET to process this particular element on the server side, with the execution determining the HTML tag(s) that will be output at that point.

Comment: Okay I get it, but what difference does it make in the end that the element is handled by the server ? I may as well use classical html form, I will end up to the same result, right ?

Comment: No, not the same thing at all. An `<asp:Label>` element will probably end up writing out an HTML `<span>`. Some ASP.NET controls will write out an extremely complex set of HTML elements for a single `asp:`-prefixed "element". There is no one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: See Henk's example above in relation to my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Asp:label is a asp.net usercontrol you can access from codebehind. label is an html tag. The asp.net control is rendered to just that.

Comment: It seems I can create an html tag <input type="..." runat="server"> and this allows be to access it from codebehind. So the asp tag doesn't really make a difference here I think...